# Override sub-method of a model

Tags: django

I have two models linked by a foreign key:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    ...

class Seat(models.Model):
    page = models.ForeignKey(Car)
    position = models.IntegerField()
    ...
```

Now I can access the set of car seats like that:

```
car = Car.objects.get(pk=123)
car_seats = car.seat_set.all()
```

I would like to override the `all()` method in order to return by default the set of seats ordered by position. I know how to override seat_set in the `Car` model, but how to override one of its method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are atleast 2 ways you can approach this issue:

- Create  a custom manager.

[Documentation on custom manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers-and-model-inheritance)

- Specify an ordering attribute

[Documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering)

```
class Seat(models.Model):
    page = models.ForeignKey(Car)
    position = models.IntegerField()
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('position', )
```

Note that this would set the ordering on `Seat` queryset by default across the board.

Ofcourse, Alvaro has another approach.

Comment: Thanks, @karthikr. I think I will go for the custom manager solution.

Comment: Yes, In my opinion that is a clean solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would't mess with managers..
Define a property:

```
@property
def ordered_seats(self):
    return self.seat_set.all().order_by('position')
```

Comment: I thought about this solution already. But I think that it makes more sense in the context of my application to have the seats ordered all the time, so changing the behaviour of seat_set (or adding an ordering attribute, as @karthikr suggested) seems better to me. Thank you anyway for your answer.